# On keystroke insert line of code in (mac)vim, for pdb

Tags: python, vim, macvim, pdb

I'm looking for the way to insert a line of code with a keystroke like <kbd>leader</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> in Macvim

I want to insert the following line of code:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Probably not an unheard of line of code in python land

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might not be the best vimscript every but it does wat you want! :-) Just place this in your .vimrc and you can call it with leader p.

```
map <Leader>p :call InsertLine()<CR>

function! InsertLine()
  let trace = expand("import pdb; pdb.set_trace()")
  execute "normal o".trace
endfunction
```

Comment: This is actually perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 12):

I'd use a simple mapping (without functions) to leader p:

```
nnoremap <leader>p oimport pdb; pdb.set_trace()<Esc>
```

When pressing o, this enters insert mode inserts a blank line after the current one (with <kbd>o</kbd>) and then types `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`, finally it goes back to normal mode (with <kbd>Esq</kbd>).

---

If you want to insert the code before the current line replace o by O:

```
nnoremap <leader>p Oimport pdb; pdb.set_trace()<Esc>
```

Or alternatively you could set this for leader shift-p:

```
nnoremap <leader><S-p> Oimport pdb; pdb.set_trace()<Esc>
```

Comment: I used a variation of this answer to insert above the current line and use the same level of indent, regardless of any indent plugins: `nnoremap <leader>p yyP^Cimport pdb; pdb.set_trace()^[` (the ^C isn't "control-v C", it's just "^" then "C").

Comment: The `^[` at the end didn't expand to ESC for me in gvim on Windows (but instead was just printed to the buffer). Using `<Esc>` instead solved this problem.

Comment: @Zakum mind the explanation on how to insert the `^[` character on the third paragraph.

Comment: Right, didn't notice! Any advantages of using `^[`to `<Esc>`?

Comment: @Zakum not really (as far as I'm concerned). I just find it easier to type :)

Answer (score 6):

Why not try the [vimpdb](http://code.google.com/p/vimpdb/) plugin? Alternatively, if your looking for snippet functionality, the combination of the [supertab](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=182) and [snipmate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) plugins works great.

Comment: I love vim, but I wanted an ide feature set. These three plugins, plus project, conqueterm, taglist, and a couple other minor ones give me the best of both worlds. And I have a working ide for specialized "languages" that I have to work with. Eclipse won't do psl.

Answer (score 2):

Using registers?

write that line somewhere and copy it to register `p`, then use `"pp` to print it

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

"pY

"pp
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

or use abbreviations

```
:ab teh the
```